# Deleting an exact item from Combo Box where the item has its duplicates

Tags: c#

I need this solution. Problem arises when  i want to remove an item which have its duplicates in data list.
Say, combo box has these items in this order : 1,2,1,3,1

When i select the 2nd or 3rd "1" to remove , every time first one is being removed. This way,i came to know that Combo Box or List Box works in STACK's way(last in first out).

What will be solution  of this situation, where i want to remove 2nd "1" ,it removes THE 2ND ONE.

Hope,i have made my problem understandable to all.

Comment: What is the code you're using right now? That will help us figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Why don't you try to avoid even placing duplicates in the combo box in the first place? It seems like you're creating extra work..

Comment: @mike You cant know without him explaining his goals. Could just be an example.

Answer (score 0):

I cant really get where your problem is. If you say its removing the first one, then you are probably removing by the text of the item. Instead of that, just select it by the index!?

*If you're deleting by clicking a button:*

```
private void OnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox.Items.RemoveAt(comboBox.SelectedIndex);
}
```